# A Noetherian scheme $X$ is integral iff it’s connected and all stalks are integral domain.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading rising sea and try to prove exercise 5.3.C:

> A Non-empty Noetherian scheme $X$ is integral iff it’s connected and all stalks are integral domain.

The “only if” part is trivial: an integral scheme is irreducible, hence is connected. It’s also obvious that stalks are integral domains.

My question is about the “if” part, stalks being integral means they are reduced. What remains is the irreducibility of $X$. Since $X$ is connected, the irreducible component of $X$ are closed, so if I can prove the irreducible components do not intersect with each other, I am done.

If two irreducible components $Z,F$ intersect at $p$, we can pick an open affine neighborhood $U$ of $p$, and $U$ necessarily contains generic points of $Z$ and $F$ in $X$.

So,my question is:

1. Did I miss anything in the argument above?
2. If I didn’t, is it true that in any affine scheme a stalk at a point where two irreducible subsets (no one belongs to the other) intersect can’t be an integral domain?

It’s easy to translate 2. into commutative algebra, but after that, I still don’t know how to solve it. Any hint will help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Your arguments are correct, you have of course left out some details. As a sanity check, you should be able to say where the noetherian property is needed. Note that the result is wrong without the noetherian property, as shown here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7477/non-integral-scheme-having-integral-local-rings

Comment: @MooS yes,noetherian property is used to claim there are only finitely many irreducible components.but I didn’t see any connection between noetherian property and 2,namely:p,q are prime ideals in a ring A,not containing each other,m is a maximal ideal containing p and q,then A_m can’t be integral domain.

Comment: You forgot that $p,q$ should be minimal prime ideals.

Comment: @MooS thanks!!!!!I never think about that before.